# What is the difference between compile fileTree & Complile jar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

This is not a coding error. this is just about usage of Android studio. I tried to google and find proper solution, but I couldn't.

In an Android studio project there is XYZ.jar file in lib folder. I can use it for compiling as below in gradle.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Then I can add same file as dependency also.

> File --> Project Structure
>   Select App from Module
>   Dependency -> +  File dependency

Then Gradle change as below

```
compile files('libs/XYZ.jar')
```

What is the difference between these compile **fileTree & compile files ?**

If we add a jar as a dependency, will it go with generated APK ?

Answer (score 2):

(Nearly) Everything can be found in Gradledocs

> A FileTree represents a hierarchy of files. It extends FileCollection
>   to add hierarchy query and manipulation methods. You typically use a
>   FileTree to represent files to copy or the contents of an archive.

In here you can read about anything you have asked for, including `files()` and `fileTree()`
https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html

---

Summarizing, you can include any `.jar` artifact from `libs` directory or a specific artifact to the compile configuration.